# Rails include javascript by File.read

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4

Here I noticed some thing hard to understand

When I use chartkick

I can do either

```
<%=javascript_include_tag 'chartkick'%>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
#put all chartkick.js content here
</script>
```

Both will work

However, if I do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%=IO.read("/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chartkick\-1.3.2/app/assets/javascripts/chartkick.js"%>
</script>
```

The chartkick won't work

Can anyone answer the difference?

Answer (score 0):

IO.read outputs newlines as /n - perhaps the output isn't valid Javascript.

Comment: Are you getting javascript errors in the console? What about when you view the source?